# Are there time zone abbreviations for UTC-12 and UTC+12?

Tags: ios, cocoa, timezone, nstimezone

I'm working on a problem where I want to do calculations on NSDates where a single NSDate gives different dd/mm/yyyy values in different time zones.

To do that I'm currently using New York City (EST) and Aukland, NZ, since they are frequently on different dates.

I'd like to be able to use the time zones on either side of the international date line, UTC+12, and UTC-12. There appears to be a standard abbreviation for UTC+12, ANAT, for Anadyr, Russia. However, the iOS implementation of TimeZone/NSTimeZone doesn't seem to recognize it. There also does not seem to be an abbreviation for UTC-12 (which would be in Alaska).

Does anybody know if there are such abbreviations for UTC+12 and UTC-12 that iOS (or Mac OS, for that matter) recognizes?

Comment: Don't use time zone abbreviations.  They are highly unreliable and inconsistent.  Use IANA TZ identifiers instead.

Comment: @MattJohnson, ok, it seems there is TimeZone class function knownTimeZoneIdentifiers that gives me an array of all identifiers. I can then use that to load each time zone in turn and get their offsets.

Comment: Please read [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), in particular the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".  This is a common mistake.  A time zone is something like `America/New_York`.  It's offset will be UTC-5 for parts of the year, and UTC-4 at other parts of the year.

Comment: Also, you might want to review [the list of TZ identifiers and their offsets on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no.

I wrote some code to fetch all the system time zones, sort them by offset, and print them:

```
typealias timeZoneTuple = (abbreviation: String, name: String, offset: Int)

let timeZones = TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary
let mappedTimeZones: [timeZoneTuple] = timeZones
  .map {key, value in
    var offset = 0
    if let timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: key) {
      offset = timeZone.secondsFromGMT() / 3600
      
    }
    return (abbreviation: key, name: value, offset:offset)}
  .sorted {$0.offset < $1.offset}
mappedTimeZones.forEach {
  let abbreviation = $0.abbreviation.padding(toLength: 4, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
  let name = $0.name.padding(toLength: 20, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
  print("abbreviation = \(abbreviation), offset = \(name), val = \($0.offset)")}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
abbreviation = HST , offset = Pacific/Honolulu    , val = -10
abbreviation = AKDT, offset = America/Juneau      , val = -9
abbreviation = AKST, offset = America/Juneau      , val = -9
abbreviation = PST , offset = America/Los_Angeles , val = -8
abbreviation = PDT , offset = America/Los_Angeles , val = -8
abbreviation = MDT , offset = America/Denver      , val = -7
abbreviation = MST , offset = America/Denver      , val = -7
abbreviation = CDT , offset = America/Chicago     , val = -6
abbreviation = CST , offset = America/Chicago     , val = -6
abbreviation = EDT , offset = America/New_York    , val = -5
abbreviation = PET , offset = America/Lima        , val = -5
abbreviation = EST , offset = America/New_York    , val = -5
abbreviation = COT , offset = America/Bogota      , val = -5
abbreviation = ADT , offset = America/Halifax     , val = -4
abbreviation = AST , offset = America/Halifax     , val = -4
abbreviation = CLT , offset = America/Santiago    , val = -3
abbreviation = CLST, offset = America/Santiago    , val = -3
abbreviation = ART , offset = America/Argentina/Bu, val = -3
abbreviation = BRST, offset = America/Sao_Paulo   , val = -2
abbreviation = BRT , offset = America/Sao_Paulo   , val = -2
abbreviation = GMT , offset = GMT                 , val = 0
abbreviation = WET , offset = Europe/Lisbon       , val = 0
abbreviation = BST , offset = Europe/London       , val = 0
abbreviation = WEST, offset = Europe/Lisbon       , val = 0
abbreviation = UTC , offset = UTC                 , val = 0
abbreviation = CEST, offset = Europe/Paris        , val = 1
abbreviation = WAT , offset = Africa/Lagos        , val = 1
abbreviation = CET , offset = Europe/Paris        , val = 1
abbreviation = CAT , offset = Africa/Harare       , val = 2
abbreviation = MSD , offset = Europe/Moscow       , val = 3
abbreviation = EAT , offset = Africa/Addis_Ababa  , val = 3
abbreviation = IRST, offset = Asia/Tehran         , val = 3
abbreviation = MSK , offset = Europe/Moscow       , val = 3
abbreviation = EET , offset = Europe/Istanbul     , val = 3
abbreviation = EEST, offset = Europe/Istanbul     , val = 3
abbreviation = GST , offset = Asia/Dubai          , val = 4
abbreviation = IST , offset = Asia/Calcutta       , val = 5
abbreviation = PKT , offset = Asia/Karachi        , val = 5
abbreviation = BDT , offset = Asia/Dhaka          , val = 6
abbreviation = WIT , offset = Asia/Jakarta        , val = 7
abbreviation = ICT , offset = Asia/Bangkok        , val = 7
abbreviation = SGT , offset = Asia/Singapore      , val = 8
abbreviation = HKT , offset = Asia/Hong_Kong      , val = 8
abbreviation = PHT , offset = Asia/Manila         , val = 8
abbreviation = KST , offset = Asia/Seoul          , val = 9
abbreviation = JST , offset = Asia/Tokyo          , val = 9
abbreviation = NZDT, offset = Pacific/Auckland    , val = 13
abbreviation = NZST, offset = Pacific/Auckland    , val = 13
```

So it looks like UTC-12, UTC-11, UTC-1, UTC+10, UTC+11, and UTC+12 are all missing from the "named" timezones that are available in Cocoa.

### EDIT:

Based on a comment from @MattJohnson, it seems that the identifiers is a better way to get the list of available time zones. Modifying my code to use identifiers instead:

```
struct timeZoneStruct: CustomStringConvertible {
  let identifier: String
  var offset: Int
  
  var description: String {
    let displayOffset = String(format: "%3d", offset)
    let displayIdentifier = (identifier + ",").padding(toLength: 30, withPad: " ", startingAt: 0)
    return "identifier = \(displayIdentifier) offset = \(displayOffset)"
  }
}
  
  
let timeZoneIDs = TimeZone.knownTimeZoneIdentifiers
let mappedTimeZones: [timeZoneStruct] = timeZoneIDs
  .map {identifier in
    var offset = 0
    if let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: identifier) {
      offset = timeZone.secondsFromGMT() / 3600
    }
    return timeZoneStruct(identifier: identifier, offset: offset)}
  .sorted {$0.offset < $1.offset}
mappedTimeZones.forEach {
  print($0.description)
}
```

That yields a list of time zones ranging from UTC-11 (Pacific/Pago_pago) to UTC+14 (Pacific/Apia)

(There are quite a few duplicates for most time zones, so the list is too long to include here.)

So it seems there are defined time zones for offsets from UTC-11 to UTC+14. There is not a time zone for UTC-12 however, even though Baker Island, at Lat/Long:  0°12'N / 176°29'W, is in UTC-12. Curious.

Comment: Baker Island is uninhabited, so it does not get a locality-based time zone ID.  If one were to describe the time zone there as a valid TZ identifier, it would be the nautical administrative zone, `Etc/GMT+12`.  (The sign is inverted in this form.)

Comment: Also, something must be wrong with your code, because you are showing the same offset for both standard and daylight abbreviations, and there indeed locality-based time zones for some of the offsets you mentioned, such as `Atlantic/Cape_Verde` which is UTC-1, `Pacific/Midway` which it UTC-11, etc.

Comment: Lastly, keep in mind that many of these abbreviations were invented, and have slowly been being replaced with their numerical equivalents in recent editions of the TZ database.  So you will find that there aren't real "abbreviations" available at all for many zones.  For more on this, see recent discussion/announcements mailing lists at http://iana.org/time-zones

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to get all timezones with their respective abbreviation.
P.S Not all timezones have their proper 3-Letter Abbreviations.

```
 let timezoneList = NSTimeZone.knownTimeZoneNames
    for i in 0...timezoneList.count - 1 {
    let locale = NSTimeZone.init(name: timezoneList[i])
    print("Region: \((locale?.name)!) Abbr: \((locale?.abbreviation)!)")
  }
```

Also total 51, 3-lettered Abbreviations are present:

```
  print(TimeZone.abbreviationDictionary.count)
```

You can also explore https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timezone for more.